# UWP: Replacing data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a very weird problem. If I've set the binding and change the binding to another property, it will not work.

Look at this simple example

```
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Subtotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("FinalTotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

When the **FinalTotal** is changed, the lblTotal text will **NOT** be changed.

Now, commented out the first line.

```
//lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Subtotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("FinalTotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

NOW IT WORKED!!!! Changing **FinalTotal** will change the lblTotal text! Any idea why?

Also, **BindingOperations.ClearBinding()** is not available in UWP. So I've tried to replace it with empty binding and it still doesn't work.

```
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Subtotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });

//remove binding - not sure if this is correct way to remove binding because
//BindingOperations.ClearBinding() isn't available in UWP!
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lblTotal, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding());

lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("FinalTotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

My questions are:
1. How to replace the binding in UWP?
2. How to remove the existing binding in UWP (ie. equivalent function to **BindingOperations.ClearBinding()**)?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Just a quess - may be change BindingMode to TwoWay?

Comment: Hi Sasha, I have tried that, but it still isn't working :(

Comment: There should an error setting bindings for "Subtotal". Does output window shows binding errors?

Comment: Hi Sasha, there is no error on Subtotal. My current work around is to create two TextBlocks. One for Subtotal and another one for FinalTotal. Try to create a simple project and you'll be able to replicate this problem.

Comment: Could it be thrown some exception on the first line?

Comment: Hi @AlexejSommer, there is no exception. This problem is easily reproducible. Just bind the TextBlock to two different fields (binding) and you will see it will not update the 2nd field/binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is declared in [FrameworkElement.SetBinding method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244257.aspx):

> **Note**  Calling the **SetBinding** method and passing in a new [**Binding**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx) object won't necessarily remove an existing binding. Instead, you should first call the [**DependencyObject.ClearValue**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.clearvalue.aspx) method, then call **SetBinding**.

So you can change your code like following:

```
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Subtotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
lblTotal.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
lblTotal.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("FinalTotal"), Source = Order, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

After this your code should be able to work. For more info, please see **Remarks** of [FrameworkElement.SetBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244257.aspx) and also [BindingOperations.SetBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244376.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jay, I have not tested this code, but it looks Ok. Will try it when I am back to work and report back if there are problems!